# Parse JSON string as an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

May seem silly for most of you but I need to parse a JSON string as an array using JavaScript.I'm completely new to JSON and JavaScript and trying to make sense since last two days.

I need to read this JSON as an array and parse it using Javascript. In this example the JSON returned is single element, however in specific cases it returns multiple results(array)

```
[
  {
    "CauseAndEffect_Status": "InProgress",
    "CurrentPhase": "Planning",
    "cityCountry": "Walker French Southern Territories",
    "location": "bangalore",
    "siteAddress": "Sharon Street Canda Avenue",
    "siteName": "DAISU",
    "status": "95%",
    "zipCode": 12940
  }
]
```

Although the above JSON is an array object,I get the following error when I try to parse this JSON

**`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data of Jquery-2.1.4.min.js`**

Comment: What array do you want exactly as your expected result?

Comment: Your pasted code is a _JavaScript Array literal_ already

Comment: @PaulS. Actually that's an *object* !

Comment: I know its an object But i do get this console message. JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @Shafizadeh `Array instanceof Object; // true` so yeah, but it starts `[` and ends `]` so we normally call those _Arrays_. @this-Me these types of errors can come from invalid invisible characters, try copying into another editor and seeing if you get a `?` or other symbol appear somewhere (such as the second char on line 1)

Comment: Then it is likely you have a problem with the source. Please show all relevant code related to getting and parsing the data shown

Comment: @PaulS. I see, you are right.

Comment: @PaulS. There seems to be no error or parsing issue if I post the same JSON on JSONEditorOnline

Comment: @this-Me in that instance either the copy/paste operation is getting rid of the char causing the error or the textbox you're pasting into isn't accepting that char. You probably would find that what you pasted here works fine too.

Comment: @PaulS.  Can you access this WebAPI http://fusionapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Site/GetSiteDetails?siteId=64909fee-e52e-4051-8277-8ba2101e743b

Comment: @this-Me check the answer now

Comment: That link is not a lot of help...where is the code that throws the error?

Comment: @this-Me the response looks like `[91, 13, 10, 32, 32, 123, 13, 10, 32, 32, ...` This means char 2 is `\r`. Perhaps you're working in an environment which does not accept `\r\n` line endings. I can perform a JSON parse on the data returned by the server without issue

Comment: @charlietfl: It throws in the Jquery as posted referred in my question, Kindly refer the same

Comment: @this-Me that's not how things work here. There are numerous reasons that error could be thrown. Please see [mcve]. Show your code if you want help

Answer (score -1):

Code For Parsing Json in Javascript . See the Js Fiddle below

```js
var str ='{"CauseAndEffect_Status": "InProgress","CurrentPhase": "Planning",    "cityCountry": "Walker French Southern Territories","location": "bangalore","siteAddress": "Sharon Street Canda Avenue","siteName": "DAISU","status": "95%","zipCode": 12940}';

var json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(json);

 $.each( json, function( ky, val ) {
        console.log('ky => '+ky);//will output: name, firstname, societe
        console.log('val => '+val);//will output: name1, fname1, soc1
    });
```

**CHECK THE BROWSER CONSOLE TO SEE RESULT**

Comment: I have updated answer and now its exactly parsing the string you given

Answer (score -1):

If it comes from the server as a string, you can use

```
var myArray= JSON.parse(myJsonString);
```

and you you'll have an array of objects myArray which you can cicle with a simple for loop

Comment: If I try to parse I get SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data